# How do I temporarily take a node out from SGE (Sun Grid Engine)?

Tags: cluster, grid

I'm having some trouble with a specific node. Until I resolve it, I don't want any jobs to run on ii. How can I temporarily take this node out of the nodes "pool"?

Answer (score 7):

To disable:

```
qmod -d *@node_name
```

To re-enable:

```
qmod -e *@node_name
```

Comment: Why is this downvoted?

Comment: As advice, I had an issue getting wildcard queue names to work. I ran a `qstat -f`, got the queue on the host I wanted to disabled and used that as the argument after **-d** in `qmod -d`

Answer (score 2):

If you're running 6.1 or better, here's the best way.  Create a new hostgroup called `@disabled`

```
qconf -ahgrp @disabled
```

Create a new resource quota set with

```
qconf -arqs limit hosts @disabled to slots=0
```

Now, to disable a host, just add it to the host group

```
qconf -aattr hostgroup hostlist MYHOST @disabled
```

To reenable the host, remove it from the host group

```
qconf -dattr hostgroup hostlist MYHOST @disabled
```

This process will stop new jobs from being scheduled to the machine and allow the currently running jobs to complete.

Comment: This does not seem to work. Jobs still get executed on the problematic. What can go wrong here? I can see it was added to @disbaled (using qconf -mhgrp @disabled) and I have enabled the quota set.

Comment: By the way, the resource quota set looks like this: `{
   name         disabled_hosts
   description  created by me
   enabled      TRUE
   limit        hosts @disabled to slots=0
}`

Comment: By the way, this did work: `{ name disabled_hosts description created by me enabled TRUE limit hosts {my_bad_host} to slots=0 }`, so I guess it has something to do with @disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your SGE version I cannot say for certain that this will achieve the desired outcome, however, `qconf -de foo` will delete the execution host *foo*. `qconf -ae foo` will then add the host *foo* back to the execution list.

Comment: This also doesn't seem to work. Jobs still get executed on th problematic node.

Comment: @David B - After removing the host does `qconf -s` still show the host?

Answer (score 0):

gridsuspend - Suspends one or more hosts from executing grid jobs.
Example:
gridsuspend -s -r "reason comment here" <host_name> 1d

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).